# Apache rewrite rule different if capture is empty

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, virtualhost

what I have so far is:

```
<VirtualHost 111.111.111.111:80>
     ServerName ex.me
     ServerAlias www.ex.me

     Options +FollowSymLinks
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteRule ^/(.*)$  http://exemple.com/foo/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

what I need is if (.*) is empty, it rewrites to http://exemple.com and if it has something, it redirects to http://exemple.com/foo/$1 -- I don't know how to do the if empty rule. right now. Right now it redirects to http://exemple.com/foo/ no matter if there is something captured or not.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 RewriteRule ^/$  http://exemple.com/ [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^/(.+)$  http://exemple.com/foo/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Wow so simple, duh. Thanks alot!

Comment: Care to explain why this is needed?

Comment: @jontro: sure, if you care to clarify what it is you don't see here? You _do_ know this is about redirecting to _another_ servername (so ate least another vhost configuration, possibly even an entirely different server)? `(www).ex.me != exemple.com`. What to OP originally wanted it for I don t know, but it seems to me a short, easily linkable domain redirects to a bigger one (like for instance `fb.com` links to its bigger brother).