# Trying to redirect blog.domain.com to www.domain.com/blog/

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm combining a main site at www.domain.com, and an old wordpress blog at blog.domain.com, into one completely new Wordpress install. I have exported and imported all the old blog posts so that they now live under wwww.domain.com/blog//

I am trying to create one rewrite rule that will map all the old blog posts to their new URLS.

I've tried variations on these SO discussions:
[DNS/.htaccess files to redirect subdomain to specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874085/dns-htaccess-files-to-redirect-subdomain-to-specific-folder)
[Apache rewrite rule different if capture is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466456/apache-rewrite-rule-different-if-capture-is-empty)

but nothing is working.

The following in my .htaccess file will redirect blog.domain.com to www.domain.com/blog, if there is nothing more in the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blog\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.domain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but if there is anything more in the URL, it does not rewrite the URL at all, and goes to the new Wordpress site's 404 page.

I tried adding a capture to the final RewriteRule line, but then no rewrite occurs, and it just goes to the new homepage but the address bar still reads "blog.domain.com":

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blog\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.+)$ http://www.domain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to remove the leading slash:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blog\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
# no slash---^
```

And make the `+` a `*`. URI's that are sent through rules in htaccess files have the leading slash stripped off, so `^/(.+)$` would never match.

Comment: Wow. 2 correct answers at the exact same time. I actually did one last search and found a solution similar to Jon Lin's right before I saw these answers. I would accept them both if I could.

Answer (score 3):

Replace your rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?blog\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/blog%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**PS:** Make sure this is the 1st rule in your .htaccess.